# Integers are set to random values after msgrcv

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I have a number of messages (which are integers) on the queue I want to consume and I want to keep track of how many messages I consume using an integer `int consumed`.

I first detect if the queue has messages using `ds.msg_qnum > 0` where ds is an object of struct msqid_ds. If there are messages then I call msgrcv to consume the message and increment the consumed counter.

So I have this:

```
msgrcv(msgqid, (void *) &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0)
printf("consumed before incr: %d\n", consumed);
consumed++;
```

And consumed shows up as the same random integer value after every message consumption. Also, I set my message struct to hold message data as type int; I am not sure if that is the smoking gun.

Comment: How is `message` declared and initialized?

Comment: Declaration: `typedef struct msgbuf { long mtype; int mdata; } message_buf;`
Initialization: `message_buf message;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to [`msgrcv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgrcv.html) is invalid. The size parameter is wrong:

> ```
> struct mymsg {
>     long    mtype;     /* Message type. */
>     char    mtext[1];  /* Message text. */
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>    The argument msgsz specifies the size in bytes **of mtext**.

You should pass the size of `msgbuf.mdata`, not the size of the whole struct. This could very well overwrite past the end of `message` and garble whatever happened to be stored there.

(Make sure you initialize `message.mtype` before calling `msgrcv` too.)

Comment: Add to this from the man page:The  msgsz argument specifies the size in  bytes  of  mtext.

Comment: Thank you, I only changed the passing size to `msgbuf.mdata` and it works successfully. I believe I read somewhere that the message struct is valid as long as the long type is declared and the type of the data is arbitrary. I am still unsure to why the data would be change my integer as my `msgsnd` was also sending the entire size of the struct. Can you clarify this?

Comment: The `msgsnd` **must** also only pass the size of the payload, not the whole struct. You were sending data past the end of your `int` in the sender (undefined behavior) and telling `msgrcv` that you had that much room in `mtext` on the receiver when you don't (undefined behavior too) - so whatever garbage was after your struct in the sender got transferred to your receiver and overwrote whatever was after `message` in memory, which just happened to be your counter. Be very, very careful with this - this type of bug can be extremely hard to debug.